# How to fix the error "You are not authorized to create, modify or lock instance error"?

Tags: pega

I have the data page DestrAct. 

When I try to call Obj-Save method in an activity the error "You are not authorized to create, modify or lock instance Org-Div-Data-DestrAct" occurs. 

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of `Access Groups` `Access Roles` and `Privileges`

Comment: No, I don't. But I would like to figure out an appropriate privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the error:

1. Open your `Access group`. You will see an `Access roles` List.
2. Open any `Access role`. You will see a table of `Privileges`.
3. Click on `Add` icon(+). A section will pop up.
4. At the top, put you class name `Org-Div-Data-DestrAct`.
5. In middle `Privileges` section put `5` in all 8 input fields.
6. Leave the bottom `Privileges` and `Access` section blank.
7. Re-login.

Now you should be able to create and update instances of `Org-Div-Data-DestrAct`